# Custom SwiftUI View with ViewBuilder parameter that takes View as parameter

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am failing to allow a ViewBuilder parameter for a custom View, that takes another view as parameter.

Something like this: `@ViewBuilder imageElementContent: @escaping (ElementView) -> EnclosingView)`

This is my current draft that is failing to compile:

```swift
struct AsyncCouponImageRendererView<ImageView, EnclosingView>: View where ImageView: View, EnclosingView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var model: AsyncCouponImageRendererModel
    private let imageElementContent: (ImageView) -> EnclosingView

    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - couponImages: List of images to be rendered as list of SwiftUI Images (CouponImage → UImage → Image)
    ///   - tandemRendering: Render the images consecutively (one behind the other). Pending image renderings will be represented with a Progress View
    @MainActor init(couponImages: [CouponImage], tandemRendering: Bool = true, @ViewBuilder imageElementContent: @escaping (ImageView) -> EnclosingView) {
        self.model = AsyncCouponImageRendererModel(couponImages: couponImages, tandemRendering: tandemRendering)
        self.imageElementContent = imageElementContent
    }
    
    @MainActor init(couponImages: [CouponImage], tandemRendering: Bool = true) where EnclosingView == ZStack<ImageView> { // edited based Dávid Pásztor's answer
        self.init(couponImages: couponImages, tandemRendering: tandemRendering) { view in
            ZStack {
                view
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(0 ..< model.imageCount, id: \.self) { index in
            if let image = model.images[index] {
                imageElementContent(
                    Image(uiImage: image)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit() // <-- compiler complains "Cannot convert value of type 'some View' to expected argument type 'ImageView'"
                )
            } else {
                ProgressView()
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            model.render()
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler complains `Cannot convert value of type 'some View' to expected argument type 'ImageView'` at line `.scaledToFit()`.

Everything works fine until the introduction of the ViewBuilder parameter.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Just updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your 2nd init that results in the compiler error, you are implicitly defining the type of `EnclosingView`.

You need to tell the compiler that this init is only available when `EnclosingView` is indeed equal to the type you are implicitly using, namely `ZStack<ImageView>`.

```
@MainActor init(couponImages: [CouponImage], tandemRendering: Bool = true) where EnclosingView == ZStack<ImageView> {
    self.init(couponImages: couponImages, tandemRendering: tandemRendering) { view in
        ZStack {
            view
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Nonetheless, the compiler still complains `Cannot convert value of type 'some View' to expected argument type 'ImageView'` at line `.scaledToFit()`.

Comment: @Maschina that error is unrelated to using `@ViewBuilder`. That error occurs even when removing `@ViewBuilder` and the convenience init.